# What are fair prices for most common goods in Cambodian markets?

Tags: price, cambodia

I have been here for almost two months now and realised that ripping off *barangs* (foreigners) is a norm here... especially so in the local markets where there are no prices listed on goods...

**What are fair prices for most common goods in Cambodian markets?**

Comment: Although useful now, I fear this question won't be that useful in the future when prices change. Seems to me like a classic case of a price shopping question.

Comment: @JoErNanO Hi, what could change is dollar to ryel ratio... local prices might, but unlikely to change all at once... and they can always be updated. Alternative of not having anything at all and get ripped off seems unnecessary... this at least indicates approximate price... I have paid 3$ for kg of mangos... and would prefer that others wouldn't have to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal trial and failure 'good' prices (in Ryel, 4000 ryel = 1$) are:

Brown Eggs 10 - 4000
White Eggs 10 - 5000
Flour 1 kg - 3500
Toast bread (large) - 5000
Pasta (weighed from bags) 1 kg - 5000
Ketchup 1 litre - 5000
Oil 1 litre - 7000
Pork (back with skin) 1 kg - 13000
Duck (whole) - 15000
Potatoes 1 kg - 4000
Tomatoes 1 kg - 4000
Bananas 1 kg - 4000 (but can get 3kg+ for 4000 if they start turning black)
Mangoes 1 kg - 3000
Papaya 1 kg - 3000
Pears 1 kg - 8000
Apples 1 kg - 8000 - 12000  (depends on flavour)
Limes 1 kg - 6000
Sugar 1 kg - 5000
Cabbage 1 kg - 3000
Lettuce 1 kg - 5000
Carrots 1 kg - 4000
Cucumbers 1 kg - 3500
Mushrooms 1 kg - 8000
Squids small 1 kg - 8000
Squids medium 1 kg - 10000
Red Fish 1 kg - 10000
Shark 1 kg - 12000
Rays 1 kg - 8000
Frogs 1 kg - 16000
Large shrimps 1 kg - 38000
Condensed milk 1 kg - 2500
Paper towels 2 rolls - 3500
Noodles 10 packs - 5500
Rice 1 kg - 2500
Onions 1 kg - 5000
Butter 450 g - 8000